# Unity, Spawn a prefab from another prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity. I have an invisible GameObject , call it A, with only a script, that instantiates a prefab B multiple times. I need spawned clones of B to have reference back to A, I have learned that in order for this to work, A has to be a prefab itself (correct me if I'm wrong) Spawned B objects react to mouse clicks and call a method of A. The problem is that inside this called method of A, the variables of A itself have values that I don't expect, for example a certain variable that was initialized to 0 in Start() and never used has a value of 12. It seems like every spawned object B has a reference to its "own" A, and variables of A have random values. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide the script that is attached to the A `GameObject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in order for this to work, A has to be a prefab itself (correct me if I'm wrong)

I assume that you are setting the relevant field in the script on prefab `B` to the *prefab* of `A`, which is not what you want. `A` doesn't have to be a prefab *at all*.

A prefab is a serialized GameObject that contains specific shared default values for easy GameObject management through the Editor and Editor/in-game scripts. A prefab is used when dealing with a large number of similar objects; each prefab instance will be similar to another with the exception of a few modified properties. This allows for large scale instantiation modification of prefab instances in a single click. For example, storing a gun projectile object as a prefab allows you to modify the default size of all gun projectiles with a single click, while allowing for property customization on a per-instance basis. You can think of prefabs as templates you can use to instantiate a GameObject.

When spawning an instance of prefab `B` through the script on `A` (henceforth referred to as `ScriptA`), simply set the required field on the script on the *spawned instance* of B (hereafter referred to as `ScriptB`) to the `gameObject` (or some other) field of `ScriptA`, like the following:

```
// ScriptA's method which spawns instances of prefab B
GameObject bInstance = Instantiate(prefabB);
ScriptB scriptOnBInstance = bInstance.GetComponent<ScriptB>();

scriptOnBInstance.referenceToAGameObject = this.gameObject;
```

Comment: At first my GameObject A was not a prefab, since I need only one instance of it; I converted it to a prefab because I was trying to give prefab B a reference to A from editor (by drag and drop) assuming that it was the correct way to give clones of prefab B a reference to A. But in this way, after editing prefab B and clicking apply, I saw that the reference to A was lost, so to avoid this I converted A to a prefab. Now I understand that this was totally meaningless and that I can give a GameObject a reference to another GameObject programmatically.

Comment: @RaffaeleTasso If the answer solved your problem, please accept it to mark this question as answered and help others with the same problem find the solution easily.

Comment: As another snippet of information, prefabs will not serialize (store) any values of fields that contain a reference to an object in the scene, because the existence of that object in _other scenes_ cannot be guaranteed. However, references to prefabs will be stored since they are serialized to disk and are accessible from anywhere in the whole project. Hence why the reference to the _scene GameObject instance_ in B's prefab was lost, but the reference to the _prefab_ was retained.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it makes sense. In the unity forum, for the same question, a user suggested to mark relevant variables and methods in object A static. Given that both solutions work, which one would you consider best practice?

Comment: @RaffaeleTasso I'd rather not use static fields for this case, since they break instantiation. If you ever decide to have more than one instance of A in a scene, static fields will need to be made instance fields and will pretty much require manual refactoring for every usage. If you use instance fields, however, you just have to change the reference to A being used in consumer scripts to a different instance of A.